# Transfer data from table to objects (Python)

Tags: python, dynamic

I am new to programming and would appreciate any advice regarding my assignment. And before you read what is following, please accept my appologies for being so silly.

### Context

Every week I receive several .txt documents. Each document goes something like this:

```
№;Date;PatientID;Checkpoint;Parameter1;Parameter2;Parameter3/n

1;01.02.2014;0001;1;25.3;24.2;40.0/n

2;01.02.2014;0002;1;22.1;19.1;40.7/n

3;02.02.2014;0003;1;20.1;19.3;44.2/n

4;04.02.2014;0001;2;22.8;16.1;39.3/n

...
```

The first line contains column names, and every other line represents an observation. In fact there are over 200 columns and about 3000 lines in each .txt file I get. Moreover, every week column names may be slightly different from what they were a week before, and every week the number of observations increases.

My job is to select the observations that satisfy certain parameter requirements and build boxplots for some of the parameters.

### What I think I should do

I want to make a program in Python 2.7.6 that would consist of four parts.

1. Code that would turn every observation into an object, so that I can access attributes like this:

   ```
   obs1.checkpoint = 1

   obs4.patientid = "0001"
   ```

I literary want column names to become attribute names.
Having done this it would be nice to create an object for every unique PatientID. And I would like objects representing observations related to this patient to be attributes of patient objects. **My goal here is to make it easy to check if from checkpoint 1 to checkpoint 2 the patient's parameter increases.**

2. Code that would select the observations I need.
3. Code that would build boxplots.
4. Code that would combine the three parts above into one program.

### What I've found so far

I have found some working code that dynamically adds attributes to instances:
http://znasibov.info/blog/html/2010/03/10/python-classes-dynamic-properties.html

I'm afraid I don't fully understand how it works yet, but I think it might be of use in my case to turn column names into attribute names.

I have also found that creating variables dynamically is frowned upon:
http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

### Questions

Is it a good idea to turn every line in the table into an object?

If so, how do I go about it?

How do I create as many objects as there are lines in the table, and how do I name these objects?

What is the best way to turn column names into class attributes?

Comment: Take a look at [namedtuple()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: [`csv.DictReader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) can handle the first part, i.e. read the data into a dictionary with column names as keys. Then you can access values using `obs1['checkpoint']`. You need to handle type conversions yourself, e.g. checkpoints seem to be numeric, but the `DictReader` will give you strings.

Comment: I think full fledged objects for every line is overkill. Dictionaries would be much simpler and lightweight. It would also make the dynamic attributes part trivial.

Comment: Yes, objects for every line is definetly an overkill. But you data just seems to be made for pandas (or vice versa^^):  http://pandas.pydata.org/. To be more specific you could put your data into a DataFrame: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.1/dsintro.html#dataframe

Comment: +1 for pandas: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#io-read-csv-table will do almost all the work for you.